# CA2202: Do not dispose objects multiple times

Tags: c#, try-catch, il, using-statement

I have a class like so...

```
public class Class1
{
    public Class1()
    {
        byte[] plainText = new byte[1024];
        using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                csEncrypt.Write(plainText, 0, plainText.Length);
                csEncrypt.FlushFinalBlock();
                csEncrypt.Flush();
                encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }
    public ICryptoTransform encryptor { get; set; }
    public byte[] encrypted { get; set; }
}
```

Code analysis throws the following warning. Do not dispose objects multiple times.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182334.aspx.

I am not able to comprehend this line in the article above [Example section]... "Nested using statements (Using in Visual Basic) can cause violations of the CA2202 warning. If the IDisposable resource of the nested inner using statement contains the resource of the outer using statement, the Dispose method of the nested resource releases the contained resource. When this situation occurs, the Dispose method of the outer using statement attempts to dispose its resource for a second time."

[image: IL for this code]

Comment: The CryptoStream might already be disposing the MemoryStream.

Comment: leppie is right, but there is no harm in disposing twice, because it won't throw an exception. Your syntax is correct and in my opinion, the CryptoStream should not touch the Dispose method of the injected stream. I would argue to supress the warning.

Comment: @Silvermind I agree with you, this is counter intuitive. Why would I expect `CryptoStream` to dipose its base stream? I may need it for later use. I believe this is a bad design which msft chosen for `IDisposable`.

Comment: It's not a bad design for IDisposable, it's a debatable design of the CryptoStream. Similar for TextReader, BinaryReader et al.

Answer (score 3):

It states that when you call `Dispose` on a resource, it will dispose all the resource which it holds. So the inner resource here `csEncrypt` which holds the outer resource `msEncrypt` on `csEncrypt.Dispose` it will have disposed `msEncrypt` as well.

Later `msEncrypt.Disopse` is called, so Code Analysis warns you about calling `Dispose` multiple times.

Comment: You've got your disposals the wrong way around. `csEncrypt` is disposed first and disposes of the object that `msEncrypt` is referencing.

Comment: +1 Technically, `CryptoStream` seems to only call `Close` on the wrapped stream, not dispose it. Considering the wording in the docs, I find that slightly surprising (even if they probably do the same thing in this case)

Comment: Thanks for your response Sriram. But why would an object lead to disposing of all the objects that have been passed to it. I am not even passing it as reference. What if I have to use the object again in the outer using?

Comment: @RahulSoni You can't, you should carefully use it in code. As Henk pointed in comments this is a debatable design. If you want to use later then you should dispose it only once when you're done with it

Comment: I checked the code in debugger and as Joachim pointed out, it doesn't seem to dispose it. It simply closes the stream. In .NET 4.5, we have this leaveOpen overload, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg712804.aspx. Will this issue still arise?