# Why do I get a "Do not dispose objects multiple times" warning on a single using clause?

Tags: c#, code-analysis, dispose

I have the following code (as an example):

```
using(Stream s = new FileStream(path))
using(GZipStream gz = new GZipStream(s, CompressionMode.Compress))
{
    //do stuff here
}
```

I am getting a `CA2202 "Do not dispose objects multiple times"` error here.  Is this simply because I don't use the `leaveOpen` parameter in my `GZipStream`?

I have gotten similar errors elsewhere with a single using statement, but apparently multiple calls to `Dispose()`.

Is it the same problem as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22244247/ca2202-do-not-dispose-objects-multiple-times), or something else?

Comment: from the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182334.aspx) you can use a try finally instead. Maybe not an answer but at least a solution (does that make sense? :))

Comment: `try...finally` is the "poor man's out". You should be searching for the root of the problem, not wrapping it in overhead to keep it "out of sight, out of mind"

Comment: I see.  I am not sure it's an exact duplicate of the other question, as I am using different objects, but I suppose others disagree.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the `GZipStream` also disposes of the `Stream`. The fix is either to use the `leaveOpen` parameter on the constructor (which doesn't make much sense in this case since you really want it closed anyway) or combine the statements:

```
using(var gz = new GZipStream(new FileStream(path), CompressionMode.Compress))
{
    // Do Stuff Here
}
```

Comment: Or you're calling `gz.Close()` (or some facsimile) within the `GZip` using statement) _(I don't know enough about GZip library to know if it does or doesn't do it on its own)_

Comment: Thanks - this is what I suspected was the problem.  I wanted to confirm.